# C# with INSERT Stored Procedure \r\n problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically i've got a very simple insert statement which

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ORDER]
    (ORDER_DATE
    ,ORDER_TYPE_ID
    ,PAYMENT_STATUS_ID
    ,TOTAL_COST
    ,SENDER_NAME
    ,SENDER_EMAIL
    ,SENDER_MESSAGE
    ,RECIPIENT_NAME
    ,RECIPIENT_ADDRESS)
VALUES
    (@ORDER_DATE
    ,@ORDER_TYPE_ID
    ,@PAYMENT_STATUS_ID
    ,@TOTAL_COST
    ,@SENDER_NAME
    ,@SENDER_EMAIL
    ,@SENDER_MESSAGE
    ,@RECIPIENT_NAME
    ,@RECIPIENT_ADDRESS)
```

The address input in the C# code is:

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_ORDER_INSERT");

db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@ORDER_DATE", DbType.DateTime, this._orderDate);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@ORDER_TYPE_ID", DbType.Int32, this._typeOfOrder.OrderTypeId);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@PAYMENT_STATUS_ID", DbType.Int32, this._statusOfPayment.PaymentStatusId);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@TOTAL_COST", DbType.Decimal, this._totalCost);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@SENDER_NAME", DbType.String, this._senderName);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@SENDER_EMAIL", DbType.String, this.SenderEmail);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@SENDER_MESSAGE", DbType.String, this._senderMessage);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@RECIPIENT_NAME", DbType.String, this._recipientName);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@RECIPIENT_ADDRESS", DbType.String, this._recipientAddress);

this._orderId = Convert.ToInt32(db.ExecuteScalar(cmd));            
cmd.Dispose();
```

The value in `this._recipientAddress` is a string of `"address line 1 \r\naddress line2\r\n\r\naddressline3"`

Anyway when I insert this into SQL it removed the '\r\n' and I don't want it to as this will get displayed later and I want the line breaks.

The RECIPIENT_ADDRESS database column is nText

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"address line 1 \r\naddress line2\r\n\r\naddressline3"`

In SQL would be:

```
SELECT 'address line 1 ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
          + 'address line2'  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
          + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
          + 'addressline3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it worked but doesn't show in SQL Management Studio when the result pane is set to display in Grid, need to set it to Display in Text.

When I do a select in C# then view the data the \r\n are still in the data.

The CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) are auto added to the database but they are not visable in the Grid view, just as if you did 'SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)' you get nothing.

Cheers guys

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace those '\n' and '\r' in the stored procedure

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ORDER]
    (ORDER_DATE
    ,ORDER_TYPE_ID
    ,PAYMENT_STATUS_ID
    ,TOTAL_COST
    ,SENDER_NAME
    ,SENDER_EMAIL
    ,SENDER_MESSAGE
    ,RECIPIENT_NAME
    ,RECIPIENT_ADDRESS)
VALUES
    (@ORDER_DATE
    ,@ORDER_TYPE_ID
    ,@PAYMENT_STATUS_ID
    ,@TOTAL_COST
    ,@SENDER_NAME
    ,@SENDER_EMAIL
    ,@SENDER_MESSAGE
    ,@RECIPIENT_NAME
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(@RECIPIENT_ADDRESS, '\r', CHAR(13), '\n', CHAR(10))