# C# Textarea value with newline save in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, textarea

I have an `insert` statement that takes the raw text from text area and stores it. We only allow editing the same value and not display them.

During the insert the newline along with slash [`abc\\ndef`] is removed for some reason by SQL Server. So what is the C# solution to this?

**Insert Statement**

`INSERT INTO Comments (Comment) VALUES (@clientValue)`

where comment is the column name and @clientValue contains the string `abc\\ndef` when viewed in the Visual Studio debugger

**Demonstration**

```
SELECT 'abc\
def' AS ColumnResult;
```

**C# Command Snippet**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Comments(Comment) VALUES (@clientValue)"
cmd.Connection = conn;
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@clientValue";
param.Value         = txtComment.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
conn.open();
```

execute the statement here

running above statement the `\` and `\n` newline from the textarea are getting removed. How do I avoid this?

Comment: @Damith updated with insert statement

Comment: how are you sure that it is being removed in SQL Server?

Comment: Is it possible that the newline is actually there, but it's getting lost after the subsequent `SELECT`? This has happened to me.

Comment: @hallie Doh, i ran a insert statement with the raw text value and it did egrunin i did check for that but no it is not getting lost

Comment: @Deeptechtons in your C# insert code are you using inline parameter or adding parameter to command object?

Comment: @Damith `CommandObj.Parameters.Add` will try with inline too and let you know

Comment: can show us snippet of your c# insert code?

Comment: @hallie added the code for the same

Comment: I think SQL Server doesn't remove \r\n characters of your input text. It just doesn't show it in Management Studio data-grid result.

It's already asked on Stack-overflow, take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050585/c-sharp-with-insert-stored-procedure-r-n-problem

Comment: @ali-bah Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the column type for the storage column? If it is varchar or text then change it to nvarchar/ntext.

If any of that doesn’t work you can simply replace /n with something like  or use html 
 but it would require that you update the string before storing it in database and before adding it back to textarea. This is far from ideal solution but it would work.